# Java webservices client slow when compared to dotnet client

Tags: java, web-services

we have DotNet webservice which is being called by two clients , one a dotnet client and other a javaclient

The problem is java client is taking longer time in processing the results when compared to dotnet client and affecting the performance greatly , i'm using axis in java

Is there any know issue with axis regarding my situation here.

also the same java client when run on linux platform still longer time to process.

please provide me some pointer here

Answer (score 2):

The root cause could be almost anything:--

- Slower hardware.
- Badly written client
- Long running windows client versus java client started on every invocation.
- Differences in configuration

  - XSD validation turned on for java client.
  - JVM memory allocation too small (java -mx 20m --default are generally very small)
  - Full security turned on vs security turned off

Differnet network routing -- is javacleint coming through scanning firewall.

Basically you need to get some monitoring tools and measure where the time is going!

Answer (score 0):

Does the Java/Axis client re-use it's connection(s) to the web service/server, or is it initiating a new connection with each request?

Comment: hi matt 

can you tell me what do you mean exactly when you say the connection is being made every time ...as i understand its just a simple http call how can you cache that connection

Comment: I'm referring to using the same Service object, or whatever your framework calls it; or if you are instantiating the object (and whatever components it uses) each time. Some objects can take long times to load.